# How to programmatically get all members of AD "Universal Groups"?

Tags: c#, python, .net, winapi, pywin32

Does anyone know how to use the winapi to get all members (users and groups) of Active Directory 'Universal Groups'?

I can use the [NetGroupGetUsers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370430%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function to get only the users for a group (applies to global groups which can only contain users). And I have tried the [NetLocalGroupGetMembers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa370601%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function which gives me all members of a local group. I can use this against a domain controller but it appears to apply only for Domain Local groups, not Universal Groups.

In this case I'm using Python win32 bindings for my call:

> import win32net
>
> members = win32net.NetLocalGroupGetMembers(server, "Universal Group
> Name", 0, 0) pywintypes.error: (1376, 'NetLocalGroupGetMembers', 'The
> specified local group does not exist.')

However, this works fine for a domain local group. Does anyone know the correct winapi function to use for this type of query? I want to get a listing of BOTH users and groups.